# Recommendations for some new books about computational contact mechanics in solid mechanics

Tags: finite-element, solid-mechanics

I want to simulate some frictional contact problems, but I'm not familiar with this field, could you please recommend some new books as introductions?thank you

Comment: The book by Wriggers comes to mind.